# Some clarification about this integration result

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, special-functions, cauchy-principal-value

I am studying special function, in particular the Exponential Integral, and I came up with this integral:

$$\int_{-3}^3 \frac{e^{i ax}}{x}\ \text{d}x$$

Now, I understood that this integral does not converge since it crosses the point $0$. I tried then to solve it in terms of principal value, setting

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-3}^{-\epsilon} + \int_{\epsilon}^3 $$

Then I tought the result would just be $Ei(-3 i a) - Ei(3 i a)$, since $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} Ei(-\epsilon) - Ei(\epsilon) = 0 $$

Yet W. Mathematical tells me the result is

$$\frac{1}{2} \left(-2 \text{Ei}(-3 i a)+2 \text{Ei}(3 i a)-\log \left(\frac{i}{a}\right)+\log \left(-\frac{i}{a}\right)+\log (-i a)-\log (i a)\right)$$

So now I am asking:

- Where do the log terms come from?
- Why are there those "2"s constants?

Comment: Might be a better question for the Wolfram developers.

Comment: @Aruralreader Excuse me? You believe W. Mathematica acted weirdly? I believe there is some mathematical deeper truth. Perhaps those who work with special functions will know.

Comment: Have you assumed that $a$ is real?  Mathematica evidently has not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your code

```
     `FunctionExpand[%]`
     `ComplexExpand[%]`
```

and the result will be

$$\int_{-3}^{+3} \frac{e^{i ax}}{x}\,dx=2\,i\, \text{Si}(3 a)$$

Comment: Oh, awesome! $$ $$